# Isn't a tag "auxiliary verbs" or "jyodoushi" necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am surprised that a tag "auxiliary verbs" doesn't exist. It is called 助動詞 and is one of the ten word classes that are basically divided into. They are "れる、られる", "せる、させる", "た", "です", "ます" and so on. I often see the questions about these. So I think a tag "auxiliary verbs" is necessary. If the name is unnatural, I suggest the intact name in Japanese "jyodoushi".

Comment: I'm not saying a tag for "auxiliary verbs" is unnecessary, just note that for られる we have [passive-voice], for させる we have [causative], for た [past], for です [copula] and [politeness] and for ます [politeness]. Of course you could add an [auxiliaries] tag to many of these questions. It would make a better case if you could point out a few questions asking specifically about these *as auxiliary verbs* and not about their function (passive, causative, past, etc.).

Comment: If we make this tag, we should call them auxiliaries, not auxiliary verbs.  Many of them are not verbs (e.g. ～ない or です).

Comment: @Earthliŋ I think the specific tags are better, just as [tag:particle-に] is a better tag than [tag:particles].  Of course, we do have the more general tag [tag:particles] as a catch-all, but I prefer the more specific ones.

Comment: 助動詞 is one of the ten word classes that are basically divided into. And 助動詞 means "words that help verbs", not verbs. So I suggest the name in English as "auxiliary helping verb".

Comment: Yes, it is one of the word classes in traditional grammar, but it is poorly named (both in English and Japanese).   "Auxiliary helping verb" translates 助 twice, so that doesn't work; "words that help verbs" mistranslates the modifier–head structure, so that is incorrect (and it's a calque of "auxiliary verb" in the first place); "auxiliary verbs" implies that they're verbal, so that doesn't work; "auxiliaries" avoids these problems while still being recognizable.

Comment: One of the reasons I suggest it is that if Japanese learners look words up in Japanese dictionaries, they must think what 助動詞 is. How about "Jyodoushi"? I knew there is a tag "renyoukei(連用形)"

Comment: We can always make a tag synonym for [jodōshi] → [auxiliaries]. But you say you "often see the questions about these". Could you point out some questions where you think such a tag would be helpful?

Comment: I think "Jyodoushi" tag is helpful for all questions about "れる、られる", "せる、させる", "た", "です", "ます" and so on. The dag can let the questioners know about a word class "jyodoushi". I think they would more understand them to understand the concept of jyodoushi.

Comment: "auxiliaries" っていうタグなら、もうありますけど、それではダメなんでしょうか。。。説明のところの和訳も「助動詞」になってますが・・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliaries

Comment: できれば「助動詞」という品詞にスポットを当ててほしいんですけど。あんまり「助動詞」と言う品詞は好まれないんですかね?まあ、私が決められることではないんで。

Comment: う～ん・・　「助動詞」は "auxiliaries", 「補助動詞」は "subsidiary verbs" ですね。。　「助動詞」を "auxiliary verbs" って言わないのは、「助動詞」って、「助けになる動詞」って意味じゃなくて、「動詞を助ける語」って意味だから、auxiliary **verbs** って訳すと「補助する**動詞** 」みたいでおかしいからですね・・・

Comment: 「助動詞」が "auxiliaries"として通じるならそれでいいと思います。

Comment: I think it gets the meaning across.  By the way, although English auxiliary verbs are in fact a kind of verb, they are often referred to by the shorter name "auxiliaries".  It's a fairly well-established term.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree with moderators'  and Chocolate's opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The tag for 助動詞

We already have the [auxiliaries](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliaries) tag:

> 助動詞. Inflecting function words or endings such as 〜ます and 〜ない. Many inflect like verbs (such as 〜(ら)れる), but many others do not (such as 〜たい), so here we will call these simply "auxiliaries" and not "auxiliary verbs". These should be distinguished from 補助動詞（ほじょどうし）, which are tagged "subsidiary verbs" on this site to avoid confusion.

It has the tag synonym [助動詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e5%8a%a9%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e), so you can type that in as well.  In addition, I've added the tag synonym [auxiliary-verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-verbs), so that if people type that in, they'll be redirected to the correct tag.

---

#### When should this tag be used?

I would suggest using the 助動詞 tag when we don't have a more specific tag, or if a question asks about 助動詞 in general.  For example, if a question is asking about 助動詞「せる・させる」, we can use the specific tag [causation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causation) instead.

Likewise, instead of the general tag [particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles), I prefer to use [particle-に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-%e3%81%ab), [particle-は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-%e3%81%af), and so on when possible.  In general, using more specific tags helps us categorize questions better.

Answer (score 2):

私もこのサイトに来るようになって気づいたことではあるのですが、日本の中学校で日本人が学ぶ文法（国語文法・学校文法）と、英語話者が日本語を学ぶ場合の文法（日本語文法）は割と異なっています。前者は古語から続く日本語の歴史体系を重視して構成されているのに対して、後者は英語などを母語とする人にできるだけ効率よく日本語を学ばせることに最適化されています。

で、基本的に「助動詞」という概念は日本語文法において**そもそも存在しません**。日本語文法では、動詞につく「(ら)れる」とか「(さ)せる」とか「ます」とか「ない」とかは「元の動詞の**活用形の一種**」ということになっており、それぞれpassive-form, causative-form, polite-form, negative-formと呼ぶことになっています。「だ」や「です」はコピュラと呼ばれる、英語の *be* に対応する特別な単語ということになっています。

[日本語の助動詞の表](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E_(%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95))を見ればわかりますが、接続の仕方も違えば自身の活用の仕方もバラバラです。外国語として日本語を学ぶ際に、助動詞という概念を覚えてこの表の意味するところを理解したうえで表を暗記しないと「読みません」のような簡単なことすら言えない、というのでは学習効率が悪すぎます。（そもそも国語文法では「読み」と「読ん」がどちらも連用形と呼ばれ、辞書などでもろくに区別すらされていません。例えば「書きた」と「書いた」のどちらが正しいのか辞書にも厳密な区別がない。歴史的には後者は前者の音便に過ぎないとはいえ、初学者には不親切です。）それよりは「読みます」を動詞の基本形として覚え、あとは「す」を「せん」にすると否定に、「す」を「した」にすると過去形にできます、などと覚える方が効率はいいわけです。「ませ」「ん」をそれぞれ独立した単語だと認識させることすらありません。

しかも教材によっては auxiliary verb のことを補助動詞（～ている, ～てしまう, ～てみる, etc）の意味で使っているものがあるようで、それも混乱の元になります。

以上が、 [auxiliaries](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliaries) というタグが存在はするものの不人気である理由です。こういう事情があるため、auxiliary (verb) という概念は、質問者のレベルをしっかり理解した上で慎重に使う必要があります。日本語文法と国語文法の違いを理解し、日本語の辞書を普通に使いこなしているレベルの人なら問題ないと思いますが、そうでない場合は助動詞という概念自体を一旦忘れ、その言い方が「日本語文法」で普通はどう教えられているのか調べる方が無難です（ちなみに個人的にはこの作業は割と楽しかったです）。私は特別に意識させる必要がある場合を除き、原則として助動詞という概念自体を説明では使わないことにしています。

釈迦に説法だったら申し訳ありません。

Comment: とても勉強になる話ありがとうございます。私もこのサイトに来て初めて、日本人が習っている日本語とは別の方法で外国人に日本語が教えられているという事を知りました。国語文法しか知らなかったので最初は戸惑っていましたが、効率的に日本語を教えるにはそのほうがいいようですね。日本語文法も知る必要があると思いました。